# bootcss.com supports IE8, but bootstrap official site doesn't? why?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

Could anyone tell me why bootcss.com supports IE8 but the official site can't?
What should I do to let my site with bootstrap.js act like bootcss.com?
(I know it's a stupid question, but just want to know the difference between the two.)

bootcss:
http://www.bootcss.com/javascript.html#buttons

official bootstrap:
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons

Comment: Is bootcss a modified bootstrap fork? It seems to be a chinese fork of bootstrap.

Comment: Not sure, I did'nt download bootcss.css and .js to try. Guess either modified website or modified bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

BootCss.com seems to be a chinese fork of the Twitter Bootstrap framework. As you may or may not know in China there are still alot of users who rely on very old versions of Internet Explorer, hence the backport of the official Twitter Bootstrap to support older IE versions.

http://thenextweb.com/insider/2013/03/01/internet-explorer-continues-growth-past-55-market-share-thanks-to-ie9-and-ie10-as-chrome-hits-17-month-low/

Also noteworthy is that supporting older IE versions is a great pain and requires extensive work to support.